# Django 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a simple API that list students their respected universities using Django Rest Framework. The url to list the data is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/students/`. After trying out the API,I got the following error

```
TypeError at /api/v1/students/
'type' object is not iterable

Internal Server Error: /api/v1/students/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 379, in initialize_request
    authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
  File "/Users/gilangramadhanilhami/Desktop/88sparses/shipment/tracking/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 273, in get_authenticators
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I was able to find some solution on StackOverflow but not much luck in finding a solution. I am using `APIView` in the `views.py` file and I want to understand why this happens when I used `APIView` (this issue also appears using `Viewset`).

I've tried changing the changing the permissions did not help. Also setting `many=True` to 'False' did not solve the issue also.

Anybody has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is the other files for better understanding of this issue

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "University"
        verbose_name_plural = "Universities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Student"
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from . import models

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'university'
        )
        model = models.Student

class UniversitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'url'
        )
        model = models.University
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import models
from . import serializers

class ListStudent(APIView):
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        students = models.Student.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**students/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListStudent.as_view(), name='student_list')
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/v1/students/', include(('students.urls','students'), namespace='students')),
]
```

Comment: Is there any more to the traceback? Can you set DEBUG=True?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've edit the question with some additional description on the error. Also this is DEBUG=True

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you've posted. Can you show your DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES setting?

Comment: It''s alright, I was able to solved it. The `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` looks like this `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'

    ),`. I was missing a comma since the value is supposed to be a tuple. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

I would consider this a minor mistake. My `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'` looks like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly'
    ),
}
```

What I am missing here is a simple `,`. It supposed to be like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
}
```

I realised that what the word "iterable" means. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh!! its just a `,` , You saved my time. thank you.